# Access to/list hidden files in objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, file

I'm using the following sniplet to list all files and directories under a certain folder:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directory];


for (NSString *file in directoryEnumerator) {
    NSString *filename;
    filename=file;
    filename= [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    processFile(filename);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not list/find files that are hidden as they start with a period (or the files created by OSX starting with '._'). So far I assumed that the standard behavior of the directoryEnumerator would be to list all files unless I tell it to exclude hidden files....

Does anybody have an idea, how to achieve that really all files are returned?

Thanks
Norbert

Comment: Have you tried using `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:` instead of `enumeratorAtPath:`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked on hidden files (`.hi-i-am-testing`) in my /tmp directory:

```
    NSString *directory = @"/private/tmp";

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:directory isDirectory:YES] includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:0 errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {

        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error at file URL %@ - %@", [url absoluteString], [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        return NO;
    }];

    for (NSString *file in directoryEnumerator) {
        NSLog(@"%@", file);
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, this code lists files that start with a period. However, the files created by OSX that start with '._' are not listed :-( Any idea, how I can get hold on these files?

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using seems overly complicated for enumerating a directory. `NSDirectoryEnumerator` should display `.hidden` directories by default, as there's an option (`NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles`) for skipping hidden files if it was desired.

```
NSString *path = @"/Path/To/Enumerate";
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                                             enumeratorAtPath:path];

for (NSString *file in enumerator) {
    NSLog(@"%@", file);
}
```

Result:

```
.DS_Store
.hidden
```

Comment: Indeed, this code lists files that start with a period. However, the files created by OSX that start with '._' are not listed :-( Any idea, how I can get hold on these files?

Comment: @Norbet, which files are you meaning exactly? creating a file with the name `._hidden` works the same.

Comment: OSX creates those hidden files for each file in a folder. It obviously stores some metadata in those files. If you do a 'ls -la' in a directory, you can see those files. However, they are not enumerated by the code above :-( I don't know what makes theses files so special. They don't carry extended attributes though.

Comment: @Norbert: `ls -la` gives me no such files, however, I think you might be meaning the files that are generated when connecting to an HFS+ file system or network share perhaps? That's the only time I've ever seen them.